# .NET Session not saving after build

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, session

I created an ASP.NET MVC application which saves its users information in sessions after the user log-ins. Nothing fancy about it, just a simple application.

Lately I noticed this weird behavior, Session just wouldn't save on first run after rebuild. And it's consistent.

Here's an example :

1. Rebuild solutions
2. Opens log-in page, enters credential
3. Log-in validated, redirects to dashboard but dashboard says no session found
4. Returns to log-in page, enters the same credential
5. Log-in validated, redirects to dashboard without problem

In a perfect situation, there shouldn't be any error in item #3 because upon validation a session is set to flag the application that a user is logged in.

I was wondering if I miss something here or it's just how Session works. I hope someone can shed some light for me.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(){
   HttpContext.Session.Remove("UserIn");
   return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string username, string password){
  bool validUser = true;
  if(validUser){
    HttpContext.Session["UserIn"] = username;
  }
  return RedirectToAction("Dashboard");
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Dashboard(){
   if(HttpContext.Session["UserIn"] == null){
     throw new Exception("No session found");
   }
   return View();
}
```

Comment: Could you show the relevant code in the 2 action? How you are storing the value and redirecting and how you are reading the value?

Comment: Can you add the code that checks for a session object in the dashboard and the validation block in the login page?

Comment: I added the code, trimmed some of the irrelevant codes. This is pretty much how the session is used.

Comment: Sorry, running this code works for me. So I guess that the problem lies in some other portion of your code which you haven't shown. Could you please post a short and concise code sample exhibiting the problem you are talking about?

Comment: In the Dashboard view, how are you checking the session object (you mentioned it says 'no session found') - Also, have you put a break in the Dashboard action next to the IF () block to see what the value of that session object is?

Answer (score -2):

I strongly recommend you use Forms Authentication and store username in principal object.

Check this post http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com.ar/2008/03/forms-authentication-with-mvc-framework.html

Comment: This has nothing to do with authentication. It's just so happen that the session being used in the example is for authentication purposes.

Comment: Has nothing to do with authenticatin but the example is for authentication purposes, pretty clear, thanks